# How to get bluetooth RSSI on android after discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I'm trying to write a program that can read the signal strength of a bluetooth device linked to my android 2.0 handset. Doesnt seem like android exposes anyway to get the RSSI unless it is during discovery. Is there any other way to get the signal strength of the device after the device has been detected? I read of a way to do it using NDK to access the underlying BlueZ API, but I dont know how to use that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

No. Only during discovery as a bundle extra (`EXTRA_RSSI`).